# Calabash UI Automation test

Tags: calabash-ios

/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/run_loop-2.4.1/lib/run_loop/device_agent/bin/iOSDeviceManager install --device-id acd9daeb11c04eebaeef3d2c4f14cf6e45f8cbc1 -a /Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/run_loop-2.4.1/lib/run_loop/device_agent/ipa/DeviceAgent-Runner.app

Unable to install Device Agent
Not able run, 
Can any one help, please.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue and discovered that it was due to my command line tools being set to the Xcode 9 beta (which I don't believe calabash supports as of right now). If you're on Xcode 9, try this:

1. Launch Xcode-beta
2. Open Preferences (Xcode > Preferences...)
3. Select the Locations tab
4. Set your Command Line Tools drop down to Xcode 8.3.3

If that doesn't work, please give us more information on the versions of iOS, Xcode, MacOS, and Calabash that you're using.